# iOS (UITableView): UITableViewCell displays wrong textLabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I first display a table with contents of an array of strings. Later, i use another array of strings to display its contents.
I set the text in the `tableVIew:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    NSString *string;
    if (condition)
    {
         string = array2[indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
         string = array1[indexPath.row];
    }

    NSLog(@"text:%@", string); // say, "house"
    cell.textLabel.text = string; //it is set correctly/as expected here, as verified by the log statement, but it shows the wrong text while displaying
    NSLog(@"text:%@", cell.textLabel.text); //same as value of variable string, "house", but it displays some other text, while it displays.

    return cell;
}
```

I also set the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: as:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if (condition)
     {
          return [array2 count];
     }
     else
     {
          return [array1 count];
     }

 }
```

Comment: try to set string like this `NSString *string = @""`;

Comment: @MohitPopat It still shows the wrong textLabel. But, 'NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text)' reports as "", correctly.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? I can't reproduce the problem using the generalized samples you provided.

Comment: You're right. The problem is not in the code i posted. Just answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional results are different in the two methods. In `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you are referencing `array2` when `condition` is true. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are referencing `array1` when `condition` is true.

To avoid these kind of bugs, I generally define a method to return an array of data based on section. This keeps the logic defined in one place in the class.

```
- (NSArray *)arrayForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (condition)
    {
         return array1;
    }
    else
    {
         return array2;
    }
    return @[];
}
```

Comment: That was a mistake i made while typing in here. Edited my question and Corrected it now.

Comment: No other problem is reproducible in the code you provided in your question. If I had to guess, I would say you are probably not calling `reloadData` on the main thread when you update the `condition`, `array1` and `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it. My mistake was, i was setting the textLabel's text, also in the `cellWillDisplay` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     cell.textLabel.text = array1[indexPath.row];
}
```